# Mysterious identity

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

Playing around with Maple I found this identity
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2k+1}{1-z^{2k+1}}=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1+z^{k}}$$
where $n$ is a positive integer, $z=\exp(\pi i/n)$. 
I was able to verify it only numerically. Does anyone know how to prove it?

Comment: Are you sure? All the expressions $1/(1+z^k)$ and $1/(1-z^{2k+1})$ have real parts equal to $1/2$ but the coefficients on the left add up to more than $n.$

Comment: @Justpassingby: The sum of the coefficients on the right is $n^2$, not $n$ (note the $n$ in front of the sum). That matches the sum of the coefficients on the left. So now we have proved that the real parts match!

Comment: @Henning Quite so. That establishes the real part of the equality then :-)

Comment: The imaginary parts then boil down to $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (2k+1)\tan\left((2k+1-n)\tfrac\pi{2n}\right) = n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \tan\left(k\tfrac\pi{2n}\right)$$

Comment: The RHS has imaginary part 0 baecause the terms for k and n-k cancel out (for k=0 it is real).

Comment: @Justpassingby: No -- that would be the case if the upper limit of the sum was $2n-1$ or $z$ were an $n$th root of unity instead of, as here, a primitive $(2n)$th root of unity. As it is, all of the $1+z^k$s on the RHS lie in the upper half-plane (except $k=0$, of course), so the imaginary part of their reciprocals are never positive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First we observe that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1} {k\over {1-z^k}} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {2k\over {1-z^{2k}}} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {2k+1 \over {1-z^{2k+1}}} 
$$

Now, by partial fractions,

$${2k \over {1-z^{2k}}} = {k\over {1-z^k}} + {k\over {1+z^k}}
$$
Hence:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1} {k\over {1-z^k}} - \bigg( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}  {k\over {1-z^{k}}} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {k\over {1+z^{k}}}\bigg) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {2k+1 \over {1-z^{2k+1}}} 
$$
Now, by combining the first two sums:

$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} {k\over {1-z^k}} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {k\over {1+z^{k}}} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {2k+1 \over {1-z^{2k+1}}} 
$$

Now let's re-write the first sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {k+n\over {1-z^{k+n}}} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {k\over {1+z^{k}}} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {2k+1 \over {1-z^{2k+1}}} 
$$

Now let's use the fact that $z^n=-1$, and combine the final two terms:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n\over {1+z^{k}}} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {2k+1 \over {1-z^{2k+1}}} 
$$

As required.

Comment: Smart answer. Very nice! +1

Answer (score 4):

Given positive integer $n$ that defines $z := \exp(\pi i/n),$ we can generalize the oddly periodic sum with
$$
S_n(x) := \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2k+1}{1-xz^{2k+1}}.
$$
The power series when $|x| < 1$ is
$$
S_n(x) = \sum_{E=0}^{\infty}x^E\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k+1)z^{2kE+E}.
$$
This simplifies with the weighted sum,
$$
\left.\frac{d}{dr}(\frac{r-r^{2n+1}}{1-r^2})\right|_{r=z^E} = 
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k+1)z^{2kE},\  \mbox{ to}
$$ $$
S_n(x) = \sum_{E=0}^{\infty}\frac{1-z^{2E}-(2n+1)z^{2En}+(2n+1)z^{2En+2E}+
2z^{2E}-2z^{2En+2E}}{(1-z^{2E})^2}(xz)^E. 
$$
We observe that $z^{2E}\to1$ correctly reduces the fraction to $n^2,\  $ the period is (almost) $n,\  $ and
$$
S_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^n}\left( n^2 - 2n\sum_{E=1}^{n-1}
\frac{(xz)^E}{1-z^{2E}} \right).
$$
Before we take $x\to1,\  $ we need to recall
$$
z=\exp(\pi i/n)\  \implies\  n = 1+\sum_{E=1}^{n-1}\frac{2}{1-z^{2E}}.
$$ 
We can evaluate our analytic sum at
$$
S_n(1) = \frac{n}{2}\left(1 + 2\sum_{E=1}^{n-1}\frac{1-z^E}{1-z^{2E}}
\right)
$$
to find the desired relationship
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2k+1}{1-z^{2k+1}}\  =\  
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n}{1+z^k}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Your identity is true. I give here the method for you to prove the point for general $n$.

One has as main preliminary remark $$\color{red}{z^n=-1\iff z^{n+k}=-z^k\iff \frac{1}{1-z^k}=\frac{z^{n-k}}{1+z^{n-k}}}$$ We make $$A=\sum_{k=o}^{n-1}\frac{2k+1}{1-z^{2k+1}}$$ $$B=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1+z^k}$$

**Example of algebraic verification: $n=6$, even.**

The odd exponents in $A$ are $\begin{cases}1\\3\\5\\7=6+1\\9=6+3\\11=6+5\end{cases}$
therefore
$$A=\left({1\over 1-z}+{3\over 1-z^3}+{5\over 1-z^5}\right)+\left({6+1\over 1+z}+{6+3\over 1+z^3}+{6+5\over 1+z^5}\right)$$
$$A=B\Rightarrow \left({1\over 1-z}+{3\over 1-z^3}+{5\over 1-z^5}\right)+\left({1\over 1+z}+{3\over 1+z^3}+{5\over 1+z^5}\right)=  6\left({1\over 1+1}+{1\over 1+z^2}+{1\over 1+z^4}\right)$$ Hence $${2\over 1-z^2}+{6\over 1+1}+{10\over 1-z^{10}}=  {6\over 1+1}+{6\over 1+z^2}+{6\over 1+z^4}$$  $${2\over 1-z^2}+{10\over 1+z^4}= {6\over 1+z^2}+{6\over 1+z^4}\iff {1\over 1+z^4}={1-2z^2\over 1-z^4}\iff z^4-z^2+1=0 $$ Since $z^6+1=(z^2+1)(z^4-z^2+1)=0$  the algebraic verification is ended.

**Example of algebraic verification: $n=7$, odd.**

$$A={1\over 1-z}+{3\over 1-z^3}+{5\over 1-z^5}+{7\over 1+1}+{7+2\over 1+z^2}+{7+4\over 1+z^4}+{7+6\over 1+z^6}=B$$ 
$$\left({1-6z\over 1-z}-{7\over 1+z}+{7z^2\over 1-z^2}+{2+5z^2\over 1+z^2}+{4\over 1+z^4}\right)={7\over 1+z^3}-{3\over 1-z^3}$$
$$\left({2z(2z^7-z^6+z^5-z^4+6z^3-z^2+z-1)\over z^8-1}\right)={7\over 1+z^3}-{3\over 1-z^3}$$ but the parenthesis equals
$${2z(5z^3-2)\over –z-1}$$ because  $$\left({2z(2z^7-(\color{red}{z^6-z^5+z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1})+5z^3)\over z^8-1}\right)={2z(5z^3-2)\over –z-1}$$
where the red polynomial is null as a factor of $z^7+1=0$. Therefore  $${2z(5z^3-2)\over –z-1}={7\over 1+z^3}-{3\over 1-z^3}= {2(5z^2-2)\over z^6-1}$$ i.e $${z\over –z-1}={1\over z^6-1}\iff z^7-z=-z-1$$ which ends the proof $n=7$.